# Piping `yes` into command doesn't work

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe

I tried the following command

```
yes | parted /dev/sdd mktable gpt
```

So that I can respond to the warning about all data on that drive being lost.

However whenever I run

```
parted /dev/sdd print
```

It still shows all the partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you [check the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/parted)? In the section with options there is:

> -s, --script
>   never prompts for user intervention

So you can just do:

```
parted /dev/sdd mktable gpt -s
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked over the help but I guess I missed it.

Comment: Indeed easy to miss. `-y` (“yes”) or `-f` (“force”) would be in my opinion more in line with similar behavior for other commands.